# Yii2 file download/display inline saved in Database Blob

Tags: php, yii2

I have this code in my view:
Relevant portion only

```
[
   'attribute'=>'attachement_fle',
   'format'=>'html',
   'value'=>function ($data){
    return Html::a('Download', $data->attachment_file);
    }
]
```

I am getting the download link with a page not found. but If I use the code like below:

```
[
   'attribute'=>'attachement_fle',
  // 'format'=>'html',
   'value'=>function ($data){
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$data->attachement_fle);
    }
]
```

I am getting the download dialog box, but the downloaded file is invalid.
my question is, how I can place a download-link for the file saved in db or display inline?

As per the link given by lubosdz - I got a method 
`\Yii::$app->response->sendFile('path/to/file.txt')->send();`

so I added the method like
`\Yii::$app->response->sendFile($data->attachment_file)->send();`

still getting the error:
on further digging - above method also expects file path for example:

```
public function sendFile($filePath, $attachmentName = null, $options = [])
```

since file is not in a filesystem, but saved in Database as Blob, what `$filePath` I will provide?

Comment: Anyone voting for close vote should have a courtesy to share the reason for the same in the comment box.

Comment: if `attachment_file` in `$data->attachment_file` contains string "abc", then you must have defined method `actionAbc` inside current controller and implement downloading logic there (code that will find where is the file and return response with download headers). See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30724938/yii2-download-file-function/30728695.